# Not able to get the GetGuestNetworkPassword trait work on the router device

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-smart-home

I'm currently working on integrating my FritzBox router with the Google Smart Home App. I've successfully connected various local devices, such as my computer as a Gameconsole, to the app using an API on my NAS.

The integration is working smoothly for all functionalities, including enabling/disabling the guest network, speed tests, etc. However, I'm encountering an issue with the GetGuestNetworkPassword command.

Problem Description:
When I attempt to access the guest network settings on my Google Nest Hub 2 device, I get prompted to enter my PIN. After entering the PIN, the loading square appears, the guest network password as a QR code should be displayed. Unfortunately, the loading never completes.

Request and Response Details:

1. SYNC Response:

```json
{
  "requestId": "4186254821521734737",
  "payload": {
    "agentUserId": "00000",
    "devices": [
      {
        "type": "action.devices.types.ROUTER",
        "traits": [
          "action.devices.traits.NetworkControl",
          "action.devices.traits.SoftwareUpdate",
          "action.devices.traits.Reboot"
        ],
        "name": {
          "name": "Router"
        },
        "willReportState": true,
        "notificationSupportedByAgent": false,
        "deviceInfo": {
          "manufacturer": "AVM",
          "model": "7580",
          "swVersion": "7.30"
        },
        "attributes": {
          "supportsEnablingGuestNetwork": true,
          "supportsDisablingGuestNetwork": true,
          "supportsGettingGuestNetworkPassword": true,
          "supportsEnablingNetworkProfile": false,
          "supportsDisablingNetworkProfile": false,
          "supportsNetworkDownloadSpeedTest": true,
          "supportsNetworkUploadSpeedTest": true
        },
        "id": "125823037498738",
        "customData": {}
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

2. QUERY Response:

```json
{
  "requestId": "9323250515783345712",
  "payload": {
    "devices": {
      "125823037498738": {
        "status": "SUCCESS",
        "online": true,
        "lastSoftwareUpdateUnixTimestampSec": 1702263739,
        "networkEnabled": true,
        "networkSettings": {
          "ssid": "Martin Router King"
        },
        "guestNetworkEnabled": true,
        "guestNetworkSettings": {
          "ssid": "Martin Router King Gast"
        },
        "numConnectedDevices": 0,
        "networkUsageUnlimited": true,
        "lastNetworkDownloadSpeedTest": {
          "downloadSpeedMbps": 71.80409032702916,
          "unixTimestampSec": 1702242312,
          "status": "SUCCESS"
        },
        "lastNetworkUploadSpeedTest": {
          "uploadSpeedMbps": 29.22374429223744,
          "unixTimestampSec": 1702242312,
          "status": "SUCCESS"
        },
        "networkSpeedTestInProgress": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

3. First Request (without challenge):

```json
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "context": {
        "locale_country": "DE",
        "locale_language": "de"
      },
      "intent": "action.devices.EXECUTE",
      "payload": {
        "commands": [
          {
            "devices": [
              {
                "customData": {},
                "id": "125823037498738"
              }
            ],
            "execution": [
              {
                "command": "action.devices.commands.GetGuestNetworkPassword",
                "params": {
                  "followUpToken": "0025f6b7588f61c3fd76bb50cb7191a0b122b5eab2e8a66d10045cc26c28f39c9f6c500ae6607609544cfd52b12fa0ff279fb61f1964"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "requestId": "4461519532043804226"
}
```

Response:

```json
{
  "requestId": "4461519532043804226",
  "payload": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "ids": [
          "125823037498738"
        ],
        "status": "ERROR",
        "errorCode": "challengeNeeded",
        "challengeNeeded": {
          "type": "pinNeeded"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

4. Request with Challenge:

```json
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "context": {
        "locale_country": "DE",
        "locale_language": "de"
      },
      "intent": "action.devices.EXECUTE",
      "payload": {
        "commands": [
          {
            "devices": [
              {
                "customData": {},
                "id": "125823037498738"
              }
            ],
            "execution": [
              {
                "challenge": {
                  "pin": "PIN"
                },
                "command": "action.devices.commands.GetGuestNetworkPassword",
                "params": {
                  "followUpToken": "0025f6b7587cd68de9c2fd3e5bdd89dda696eec72cbda421b0afb4eb777c45f9daba3fb4ee441a23b001ad42719440300ffd5a6fee31"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "requestId": "4461519532043804226"
}
```

Response:

```json
{
  "requestId": "4461519532043804226",
  "payload": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "ids": [
          "125823037498738"
        ],
        "status": "SUCCESS",
        "states": [
          {
            "guestNetworkPassword": "PASSWORD"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

5. Cloud Console Log:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "executionLog": {
      "executionResults": [
        {
          "actionResults": [
            {
              "device": {
                "deviceType": "ROUTER"
              },
              "action": {
                "actionType": "NETWORKCONTROL_GET_GUEST_NETWORK_PASSWORD",
                "trait": "TRAIT_NETWORK_CONTROL"
              },
              "status": {
                "isSuccess": false,
                "statusType": "CHALLENGE_NEEDED"
              }
            }
          ],
          "executionType": "PARTNER_CLOUD",
          "latencyMsec": "112",
          "requestId": "4461519532043804226"
        }
      ]
    },
    "locale": "de-DE"
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if the Cloud Log is even relevant because I have implemented the challenge as you can see.

I've already tried to add the `followUpToken` to the `commands` body in the response. Also I tried to add some of the QUERY response states like the SSID of the guest network to the state body of the `GetGuestNetworkPassword` command.

Am I missing something in the implementation, or is there a different approach I should take?

Comment: I'm sorry to hear about the issue you're experiencing with GetGuestNetworkPassword trait.  To address this problem and ensure that it reaches the appropriate teams for investigation, I recommend opening a bug report on the [Google Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/).
Make sure to attach logs, screenshots and videos of the issue. Provide the bugID here so we can track the issue further.

Comment: @ArmenSarkisyan I was able to get it working in the end, I will create a proper response for this thread if someone else needs help on that. The documentation for the `GetGuestNetworkPassword` trait has no infomration about the `followUpToken` which is very important for this trait...